# Mark debit card number with 12 asteriks and each group of 4 are followed by space in Automapper

Tags: c#, string, automapper

```
private void RegisterDebitCardsBackofficeMapping()
        {
            CreateMap<DebitCardDto, UserDebitCardResponse>()
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.ObscuredPan,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(
                        src => src.ObscuredPan
                            .Substring(src.ObscuredPan.Length - 4)
                            .PadLeft(src.ObscuredPan.Length, '*')));
        }
```

So far I managed to mark all 12 digits with asterikses followed by the last 4 digits.

I am unable to think of easy way(like one line) to separate it with spaces.

The result I want to get is:

**** **** **** 1234

Currently I have:

************1234

Comment: "**** **** **** " + src.ObscuredPan
                            .Substring(src.ObscuredPan.Length - 4)

Comment: It is very ugly though. I thought something with using .Substring , .Replace, .PadLeft

Comment: The fixed string is the way to go. Its gonna be your cleanest solution. Any other solution is going to be more resource intensive, for no actual gains.

Comment: What is ugly about appending two string together?  Much simpler than a replace.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
private void RegisterDebitCardsBackofficeMapping()
{
    CreateMap<DebitCardDto, UserDebitCardResponse>()
        .ForMember(
            dest => dest.ObscuredPan,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => "**** **** **** " + 
                src.ObscuredPan.Substring(src.ObscuredPan.Length - 4)));
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well. For code organization I would encapsulate into a `IValueConverter<string,string>` and use it as follows: 
`.ForMember(dest => dest.ObscuredPan, opt =>opt.ConvertUsing(new YourValueConverter(), src => src.ObscuredPan))`

Comment: @Oignon_Rouge good point. If you needed to reuse this functionality anywhere, you would want to encapsulate it. +1